# Accidentally deleted nodejs.log, now Openshift doesn't log anything.

Tags: node.js, logging, openshift

In my Openshift app I deleted `/app-root/logs/nodejs.log` file in which it logs everything, and now it's not logging anything.

How do I reset it back to get it to start logging again?

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to recreate the file, set the permissions same as the other log files (0644) and restart the app

```bash
$ rhc ssh -a appname
Connecting to id52@app-name.rhcloud.com ...
[app-name.rhcloud.com id52]\> cd app-root/logs
[app-name.rhcloud.com logs]\> touch nodejs.log
[app-name.rhcloud.com logs]\> chmod 0644 nodejs.log
[app-name.rhcloud.com logs]\> exit
Connection to app-name.rhcloud.com closed.
$ rhc app-restart -a appname
```